# Convert cypher query involving split and toint to C#

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I have just started using neo4j client for my neo4j project and am facing difficulty converting the below cypher query to C#. Particularly with split and toint functions.

It would be great if you could help me out with this as Ive been trying over this for a long time now. I have even looked other web resources but couldn't gain much from them. Thanks for helping.

```
MATCH 
    (a:Airport {city:"LAX"})-[:has_flight]->(f:Flight {dep_date:"2017-07-27"})-[:flies_to]->(b:Airport)-[:has_flight]->(f2:Flight)-[:flies_to]->(c:Airport {city:"CLO"}) 
WITH 
    a,b,c,f,f2,
    split(f.arr_date,"-") as dd, 
    split(f2.dep_date,"-") as dd2 
WHERE 
    toint(dd2[2]) - toint(dd[2])>=0 
    AND toint(dd2[2])- toint(dd[2]) <=1 
RETURN 
    f,f2,a.city,b.city,c.city
```

Comment: For those of us out there who don't know neo4j, but do know c# , can you write out the algorithm in english? It'll be a lot easier to help convert it to c# that way..

Answer (score 0):

You need to break down the query into it's constituent parts, which is easier if you use new lines:

```
//MATCH
match (a:Airport {city:"LAX"})-[:has_flight]->(f:Flight {dep_date:"2017-07-27"})-[:flies_to]->(b:Airport)-[:has_flight]->(f2:Flight)-[:flies_to]->(c:Airport {city:"CLO"}) 

//WITH
with a,b,c,f,f2,split(f.arr_date,"-") as dd, split(f2.dep_date,"-") as dd2 

//WHERE
where toint(dd2[2]) - toint(dd[2])>=0 
and toint(dd2[2])- toint(dd[2])<=1 

//RETURN
return f,f2,a.city,b.city,c.city
```

Once you have that it's pretty simple to convert to `Neo4jClient`, for example:

```
client.Cypher
     .Match("(a:Airport {city:"LAX"})-[:has_flight]->(f:Flight {dep_date:"2017-07-27"})-[:flies_to]->(b:Airport)-[:has_flight]->(f2:Flight)-[:flies_to]->(c:Airport {city:"CLO"})")
     .With("a,b,c,f,f2,split(f.arr_date,"-") as dd, split(f2.dep_date,"-") as dd2")
     .Where("toint(dd2[2])- toint(dd[2])<=1")
     .AndWhere("toint(dd2[2])- toint(dd[2])<=1")
     .Return((f,f2,a.city,b.city,c.city) => new {
        Flight1 = f.As<Flight>(),
        Flight2 = f2.Asflight>(),
        City1 = a.As<Airport>().City,
        City2 = b.As<Airport>().City,
        City3 = c.As<Airport>().City
     });
```

Obviously this assumes you have a `Flight` and `Airport` class.